# counters of \declaretheorem and \newtheorem differ

Tags: counters, thmtools, newtheorem

I want to use `thmtools` in order to state questions, that I want to repeat at a latter point of my text. 
I declared the question-environment using `\declaretheorem`, but I also use theorem-environments I declared with `\newtheorem`. I want to have them to be numbered with the same counter (subsection), but it does not work. 
Can you help me out please?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,thmtools}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[subsection]
\declaretheorem[name=Question,numberwithin=subsection]{question}
\begin{document}
\section{Section1}
\subsection{Subsection1}
\begin{theorem}
test1
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}
test2
\end{theorem}
\begin{restatable}{question}{questionone}
What it is all about?
\end{restatable}
\questionone*
\begin{theorem}
test 3
\end{theorem}

\begin{restatable}{question}{questiontwo}
Hmm?
\end{restatable}

\questiontwo*

\end{document}
```

[image: theoremnumberingdoesntwork]

Comment: That is not what you are doing, you are creating two separate counters both dominated by subsection. You're probably looking for a method of using a common counter, which should be described in the thmtools manual. Note that newtheorem in your case create a counter called theorem, so you just need to tell declaretheorem to use thst counter instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Thanks, if I change tell declaretheorem to use this counter, I get the problem, that it the first Question gets the number 1.1.2.1, but I actually want it to get number 1.1.3. Do you know an instant solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

[image: demo]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,thmtools}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[subsection]
\newtheorem{question}[theorem]{Question}
\begin{document}
\section{Section1}
\subsection{Subsection1}
\begin{theorem}
test1
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}
test2
\end{theorem}
\begin{restatable}{question}{questionone}
What it is all about?
\end{restatable}
\questionone*
\begin{theorem}
test 3
\end{theorem}

\begin{restatable}{question}{questiontwo}
Hmm?
\end{restatable}

\questiontwo*

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for and it works for me. I tried it this way before, but `\newtheorem{question}[theorem]{Question}` was in the cls.file, and I had the same problem as stated in my comment on my post. Do you know why?

Comment: Order in which they are loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Original Poster's 4th line of code:

```
\declaretheorem[name=Question,numberwithin=subsection]{question}
```

Replace that with the line below, use **sibling** instead of **numberwithin**:

```
\declaretheorem[name=Question,sibling=theorem]{question}
```

That should be enough for you to get the desired output.